# "Kind of Duality result" for the volume of a $d$-ball

Tags: measure-theory

I want to prove the following "duality" and don't know how to get started... Does it have anything to with covering theorems?

$\limsup_{r\rightarrow0} \sup_{y \in B_r (x)} V^{-1} \int_{B_r (y)}f \mathrm{d}m^d = \liminf_{r\rightarrow0} \inf_{y \in B_r (x)} V^{-1} \int_{B_r (y)}f \mathrm{d}m^d$

where $V$ denotes the volume of $d$-ball with Radius $r$ and $m^d$ the $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure and $f$ is in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^d;\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: ok I think it definitly has something to do with the Besicovitch covering theorem and an statement abount the centers of balls...

Comment: nobody an idea ... ;)?